# Regex to find theme information on wordpress based sites

Tags: regex

I'm trying to build a script that will go into a css file of any given wordpress site and retrieve the theme information. Problem is - when i scrape the page, all the line breaks turn into spaces and the order is always different. For example:

```
/*
Theme Name: ColorWay
Theme URI: http://www.inkthemes.com/wp-themes/colorway-wp-theme/
Description: Colorway is Simple, Elegant, Responsive and beautiful Theme with Easy Customization Options built by InkThemes.com. The Customization Options includes using your own Logos, Backgrounds, Analytics and your own Custom Footer Texts and Analytics that can be tweaked using Theme Options Panel. Colorway Theme is Single Click Intall feature, Just press activate button and your website will get ready with all the dummy content. Just set the content from the Themes Options Panel. Colorway by InkThemes.com is suitable for any business or personal website. The Theme can work for various different niches. It includes special styles for Gallery pages, and has an optional fullwidth page template as well.
Author: InkThemes.com
Author URI: http://www.inkthemes.com
Version: 2.5.1
License: GNU General Public License
License URI: license.txt
Tags: black, blue, green, white, gray, custom-menu, dark, two-columns, fixed-width, custom-header, custom-background, threaded-comments, sticky-post, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, light, theme-options, editor-style
*/
```

This would be easy, however after scraping, I get this:

```
/* Theme Name: ColorWay Theme URI: www.inkthemes. com/wp-themes/colorway-wp-theme/ Description: Colorway is Simple, Elegant, Responsive and beautiful Theme with Easy Customization Options built by InkThemes.com. The Customization Options includes using your own Logos, Backgrounds, Analytics and your own Custom Footer Texts and Analytics that can be tweaked using Theme Options Panel. Colorway Theme is Single Click Intall feature, Just press activate button and your website will get ready with all the dummy content. Just set the content from the Themes Options Panel. Colorway by InkThemes .com is suitable for any business or personal website. The Theme can work for various different niches. It includes special styles for Gallery pages, and has an optional fullwidth page template as well. Author: InkThemes.com Author URI: www. inkthemes. com Version: 2.5.1 License: GNU General Public License License URI: license.txt Tags: black, blue, green, white, gray, custom-menu, dark, two-columns, fixed-width, custom-header, custom-background, threaded-comments, sticky-post, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, light, theme-options, editor-style */
```

Just a block of text. How would you go about doing this?

Edit:

This is an example that would work if the code wasn't in one line:

My apologies, I thought you were referring to the URL where I wanted to scrape.

here is an example that works on the source code if i just copy it:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://website-addons.net/wp-content/themes/powermag/style.css?ver=all');
          preg_match("/Theme\sName:\s?(.+)/", $html, $themename);
          preg_match("/Theme\sURI:\s?(.+?)\s/", $html, $uri);
          preg_match("/Version:(\s?.+?)\s/", $html, $version);
          preg_match("/Description:(.+)\s/", $html, $desc);
          preg_match("/Author:(.+?)\s/", $html, $author);
      echo $themename[1];
```

Doing that now wouldn't work. I would just get a whole bunch of code.

Comment: well here it comes out the same, but on the actual css file there is a line break after every subject...

Comment: start by updating your sample code if you have any and where the issue is at, your question right now is simple off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for fixing up the code Prix. The issue is on every single wordpress site.

Comment: here is an example:
http://website-addons.net/wp-content/themes/powermag/style.css?ver=all

The code at the top (between the comments) becomes one line of code.

Any ideas?

Comment: You haven't showed us any code, you haven't told us where in your code you're having your issues, but you do tell us `when i scrape the page` so again, start by posting some of your code, more precisely, of what you have tried in order to ***achieve your goal with your regex or any other means.***

Comment: I tried your example but replacing _file_get_html_ by _file_get_contents_ and it is working fine. Could you try that also and let us know?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I guess it could be done for both single and multiple lines.

```
 # '/(?s)^(?=.*?\bTheme[ ]+Name:[ ]*(?<theme_name>(?&info)))?(?=.*?\bTheme[ ]+URI:[ ]*(?<theme_uri>(?&info)))?(?=.*?\bDescription:[ ]*(?<desc>(?&info)))?(?=.*?\bAuthor:[ ]*(?<author>(?&info)))?(?=.*?\bAuthor[ ]+URI:[ ]*(?<author_uri>(?&info)))?(?=.*?\bVersion:[ ]*(?<version>(?&info)))?(?=.*?\bLicense:[ ]*(?<license>(?&info)))?(?=.*?\bLicense[ ]+URI:[ ]*(?<license_uri>(?&info)))?(?=.*?\bTags:[ ]*(?<tags>(?&info)))?(?(1)|(?(2)|(?(3)|(?(4)|(?(5)|(?(6)|(?(7)|(?(8)|(?(9)|(?!))))))))))(?(DEFINE)(?<info>(?-s:(?![ ]*\b(?:Theme[ ]+Name:|Theme[ ]+URI:|Description:|Author:|Author[ ]+URI:|Version:|License:|License[ ]+URI:|Tags:)).)*))/'


 (?s)                                    # Dot all modifier
 ^                                       # BOS
                                         # Series of lookaheads, optional (ie. independent order, change if need be)
 (?=
      .*? \b Theme [ ]+ Name: [ ]* 
      (?<theme_name> (?&info) )               # (1), Theme, optional
 )?
 (?=
      .*? \b Theme [ ]+ URI: [ ]* 
      (?<theme_uri> (?&info) )                # (2), Theme URI, optional
 )?
 (?=
      .*? \b Description: [ ]* 
      (?<desc> (?&info) )                     # (3), Description
 )?
 (?=
      .*? \b Author: [ ]* 
      (?<author> (?&info) )                   # (4), Author
 )?
 (?=
      .*? \b Author [ ]+ URI: [ ]* 
      (?<author_uri> (?&info) )               # (5), Author URI
 )?
 (?=
      .*? \b Version: [ ]* 
      (?<version> (?&info) )                  # (6), Version
 )?
 (?=
      .*? \b License: [ ]* 
      (?<license> (?&info) )                  # (7), License
 )?
 (?=
      .*? \b License [ ]+ URI: [ ]* 
      (?<license_uri> (?&info) )              # (8), License URI
 )?
 (?=
      .*? \b Tags: [ ]* 
      (?<tags> (?&info) )                     # (9), Tags
 )?

 (?(1)                                   # Conditional, Fail if nothing matched
   |  (?(2)
        |  (?(3)
             |  (?(4)
                  |  (?(5)
                       |  (?(6)
                            |  (?(7)
                                 |  (?(8)
                                      |  (?(9)
                                           |  (?!)
                                         )
                                    )
                               )
                          )
                     )
                )
           )
      )
 )

 (?(DEFINE)                              # Subroutines
      (?<info>                                # (10 start), Info
           (?-s:                                   # Cluster, data is on same line (remove '-s' if need be)
                (?!                                     # Blacklist - Not any other categories, add more here
                     [ ]*                                    # trim spaces before next block
                     \b 
                     (?:
                          Theme [ ]+ Name: 
                       |  Theme [ ]+ URI: 
                       |  Description: 
                       |  Author: 
                       |  Author [ ]+ URI: 
                       |  Version: 
                       |  License: 
                       |  License [ ]+ URI: 
                       |  Tags: 
                     )
                )
                .                                       # Grab a data character
           )*                                      # End Cluster, do 0 to many times
      )                                       # (10 end)
 )
```

Output: Used on multi-line sample:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 0 )  EMPTY 
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 16 , len 8 ) 
ColorWay
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 37 , len 53 ) 
http://www.inkthemes.com/wp-themes/colorway-wp-theme/
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 105 , len 699 ) 
Colorway is Simple, Elegant, Responsive and beautiful Theme with Easy Customization Options built by InkThemes.com. The Customization Options includes using your own Logos, Backgrounds, Analytics and your own Custom Footer Texts and Analytics that can be tweaked using Theme Options Panel. Colorway Theme is Single Click Intall feature, Just press activate button and your website will get ready with all the dummy content. Just set the content from the Themes Options Panel. Colorway by InkThemes.com is suitable for any business or personal website. The Theme can work for various different niches. It includes special styles for Gallery pages, and has an optional fullwidth page template as well.
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 814 , len 13 ) 
InkThemes.com
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 841 , len 24 ) 
http://www.inkthemes.com
 **  Grp 6 -  ( pos 876 , len 5 ) 
2.5.1
 **  Grp 7 -  ( pos 892 , len 26 ) 
GNU General Public License
 **  Grp 8 -  ( pos 933 , len 11 ) 
license.txt
 **  Grp 9 -  ( pos 952 , len 221 ) 
black, blue, green, white, gray, custom-menu, dark, two-columns, fixed-width, custom-header, custom-background, threaded-comments, sticky-post, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, light, theme-options, editor-style
 **  Grp 10 -  NULL
```

Output: Used on single-line sample:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 0 )  EMPTY 
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 15 , len 8 ) 
ColorWay
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 35 , len 47 ) 
www.inkthemes. com/wp-themes/colorway-wp-theme/
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 96 , len 700 ) 
Colorway is Simple, Elegant, Responsive and beautiful Theme with Easy Customization Options built by InkThemes.com. The Customization Options includes using your own Logos, Backgrounds, Analytics and your own Custom Footer Texts and Analytics that can be tweaked using Theme Options Panel. Colorway Theme is Single Click Intall feature, Just press activate button and your website will get ready with all the dummy content. Just set the content from the Themes Options Panel. Colorway by InkThemes .com is suitable for any business or personal website. The Theme can work for various different niches. It includes special styles for Gallery pages, and has an optional fullwidth page template as well.
 **  Grp 4 -  ( pos 805 , len 13 ) 
InkThemes.com
 **  Grp 5 -  ( pos 831 , len 19 ) 
www. inkthemes. com
 **  Grp 6 -  ( pos 860 , len 5 ) 
2.5.1
 **  Grp 7 -  ( pos 875 , len 26 ) 
GNU General Public License
 **  Grp 8 -  ( pos 915 , len 11 ) 
license.txt
 **  Grp 9 -  ( pos 933 , len 224 ) 
black, blue, green, white, gray, custom-menu, dark, two-columns, fixed-width, custom-header, custom-background, threaded-comments, sticky-post, custom-colors, custom-header, custom-menu, light, theme-options, editor-style */
 **  Grp 10 -  NULL
```

Comment: Wow, that's some serious code...!
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to even begin to use that...
Kind of a beginer...